# Can we have a books.stackoverflow.com?

Tags: feature-request

Instead of "question", we would have "book" and instead of "answer", we would have "review". There might even be a way for Jeff and Joel to hook into Amazon so if someone uses books.stackoverflow.com to buy a book, they can be the referrer and get some money.

If this is a good idea and works well on SO, then maybe SF and SU can get their own books section too.

This was inspired by [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058333/jquery-book-recommendation-and-can-we-have-a-books-reference-wiki-on-so).

EDIT: I should have clarified, but these would be books relating to the subject matter of StackOverflow (computer science, software engineering, programming), ServerFault (IT, system admin), and SuperUser (power user, software applications).

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/671/using-the-stack-overflow-knowledge-exchange-engine-for-product-reviews

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6426/books

Comment: Would there be enough books to make this worthwhile? There are only so many books. Could we maybe have a tag for each book and then expand the scope to reviews, corrections, and inspired projects? I guess that this wouldn't fit under the Q&A format, but SE should expand it's services to try to gain more users.

Comment: This subject is now covered by the new Stack Exchange Area 51. And thus is no longer relevant.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I propose a new site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Tom made a point about it being a good idea for a hosted version of StackOverflow, which I could agree with more if it was towards a wider range of topics/audiences. But a book review section which is devoted to programming books I could definitely see as a fun and useful sub-area of StackOverflow.com itself. The idea about Jeff & Joel working out a partnership with Amazon or other book dealers is great as well.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure that they could do it. I just think that it would end up being more work than it's worth. As you point out, there are questions asking for good books to read on any given topic on Stack Overflow already. Do a search and you have your wish. Moreover, with the rate of new books entering the market, it could end up being a full-time job, keeping "books page" up to date.

Comment: We already have some people who spend umpteen hours a week on StackOverflow and that includes editing questions not just asking/answering. It wouldn't be a surprise to find some people immediately drawn towards it and make it their own little project to keep up.

Comment: I do know that I would add my library to such a site, and write reviews for the books that I own.

Comment: I would definitely contribute myself, and definitely use a site described above towards future purchasing for my library (and for suggestions to our office library)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a good idea for a [hosted version of stackoverflow](http://stackexchange.com).

Comment: I'm thinking that the current stack overflow should have it. It kind of makes sense, IMO.

Comment: BookReviewOverflow.com: built with StackExchange!