# How can I propose a new site?

Tags: support, faq, area-51, site-proposal

I have an idea or subject that should have a Q&A, and want to propose a new site. How can I do this?

*Related:* [What makes a winning site proposal?](/questions/52066/what-makes-a-winning-site-proposal)

[Return to FAQ index](/q/7931)

Answer (score 132, accepted):

If you want to propose a site where English will not be the primary language, please read [Internationalization 'State of the Stack'](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20988) (or [for Stack Overflow alike sites](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20987)) first.

Otherwise, please follow the below steps:

1. Check if the subject/idea is not already covered on any of the [current sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites), and not a part of [the disallowed topics for new proposals](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/350159/208518).
2. Go to [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com).
3. Search for a proposal. If already exists follow/commit and share it. Otherwise follow next steps.
4. Select the appropriate category on the left.
5. Scroll down to the bottom of the page.
6. Click the link entitled "Propose a new [topic] site".

As always, it is advisable to search for the topic of your proposal to ensure that you don't create a duplicate. Make sure **you already have enough people** that you can reach out to **before creating the proposal**, to [get the proposal off the ground](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27938/changes-to-the-area-51-process-v3-0).

If you are not sure about the scope of your proposal, you can discuss your ideas about the proposal on the [Area 51 Discussion Zone](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It requests my "organization or website". But I don't have a relevant organization or website. Does it mean I can't propose a new SE (urban studies)?

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev that's correct. SE learned this the hard way, after hundreds of proposals closed due to lack of enough people to follow it.