# How to create a new Area 51 proposal?

Tags: support, area-51, site-proposal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I propose a new site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site)

I can't find **anything** on Area 51 where a link is provided to create a new proposal.

What happened to the page? Am I missing it somewhere, or is there a reason no new proposals are being accepted?

Comment: It's just really obscure now: you have to select a category and scroll all the way down to find the link. It really should be more prominent.

Comment: @waiwai933: You're right. That's waaaaaaay to difficult to find though.