# Here is a site for "WordPress answers". Why not for Joomla?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51, site-proposal, wordpress-se

There is a site for "[WordPress answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)", and it's very useful for developers.
Is there any for [Joomla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joomla), [Magento](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magento), [Zend Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zend_Framework), [Smarty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smarty), etc.?

It would be very useful if they existed.

Comment: See Area51 for that.

Comment: I still don't understand why we need separate sites for development tools. Why not a ".NET Answers" site, too? These questions are certainly on-topic on Stack Overflow—is the worry that it's going to start overflowing itself?

Comment: ya.actually not needed separately, but for WordPress that is there, thats y i asking for another if exist...Thanks.

Comment: As noticed by various users, this is [tag:status-completed] for Joomla and Magento. Otherwise, it's covered by [How can I propose a new site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76974/295232)

Comment: @CodyGray-onstrike Not only technological reasons exist. Having a different site means also different communities. On this way, at least a little freedom and welcomingness can exist in the background of the psychotically hostile, braindamaged crazy stack overflow.

Answer (score 6):

There is [a proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/31698/joomla) about Joomla and it has been closed as a duplicate of Stack Overflow, CMS, CMS & Blog Engines.

Comment: This answer is obsolete. The proposal was delete but still  there is a site for [Joomla](https://joomla.stackexchange.com) (probably there is another proposal).

Answer (score 3):

Since this question was posted, several new sites have been created, including a site for Joomla, Magento, and some match the "etc.". There are **25 sites**, including the word **developers**, in the site excerpt.

The site expert is built with data from a property called **audience** from the [site](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/site) type that could be retrieved using the Stack Exchange API.

The complete list of sites is on https://stackexchange.com/sites. If you think that a site is missing, please note that below the site list, there is the following statement:

> Want to start your own Stack Exchange Q&A site? [Check out Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/). Our friendly robots are waiting.

Also, you can find the complete list on the Stack Exchange menu.

---

There is a site for Joomla -> https://joomla.stackexchange.com. It's 9 years old and has more than 7k questions.

There's also a site for Magento -> https://magento.stackexchange.com. It's 10 years old. It has more than 100k questions.