# Russian Language and Usage

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-exchange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I propose a new site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site)

What about creating this Stack Exchange site? For example, there are sites abut German and Japanese languages.

Answer (score 6):

It is already being suggested.
See

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10848/russian-language-usage

> Proposed Q&A site for students, teachers, and linguists wanting to discuss the finer points of the Russian language.