# How to open a Stack Exchange site on your own topic?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I propose a new site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site)

There are a number of Stack Exchange sites for programming, computer science, music etc. I am interested to know how to open one like that.

Comment: [area51.stackexchange.com](http://area51.stackexchange.com)