# Stack Exchange site about sexuality or sexology

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

There should be plenty of reasons why a Stack Exchange site about either sexuality or sexology would be successful.

Among other things, humanity as a group depends entirely on sexual reproduction, in the same way as a human being as an individual depends on breathing.

Comment: If you have an idea for a new proposal, it's better to [just propose it](http://area51.stackexchange.com) and see what kind of feedback it receives, provided that it's not a duplicate. Discussions surrounding specific questions or problems with current proposals are held in the [discussion area](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/). While related to the network, such discussions really aren't on topic here.

Comment: Should not the question be migrated to area51?

Comment: @Mistu4u - SE generally doesn't migrate questions unless they're really outstanding and will help lots and lots of future vistors.

Comment: @Tim Post It's more likely that newcomers with questions like this, end up in a similar situation, there should be a question already answered pointing to those sites. Don't you think?

Comment: @rraallvv: [How can I propose a new site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Funnily enough, we did have a site about sexuality and it didn't do so hot, so [we had to close it down](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3303/sexuality).

Our sites are created through our "Area 51" process where a proposal must gain a certain following before we create a site for the topic, and there's another proposal up right now for [Human Sexuality](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40921/human-sexuality).

Feel free to follow that one, or propose your own if you think the existing proposal is not in line with what you had in mind.

Comment: Oh! thanks, I wasn't aware of that. How can I follow the proposal?

Comment: @rraallvv Sign into Area 51 the same way you sign into this site (there should be a "log in" link at the top), and then click the "Follow it" button on the proposal. You can also read more about the Area 51 process [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq). :)

Comment: How the hell are new proposed sites supposed to gain traction, if you’re practically keeping them a secret though? 
I would have been very interested, and spread it to a big community, but I never even heard of it.
Could you look into improving this “discovery” process?

Also, why a site needs traction at all, given it’s literally just a few bytes in a otherwise huge database, is also a riddle. It could grow organically, over years or even decades, and still become great. Hell, given a well-designed back-end, I as a single user probably use up more database space. :D