# What does it take to establish a language related stack exchange site?

Tags: feature-request, languages

I have noticed there are not many language related stack exchange sites: There are German, English, Japanese, French, Spanish, Chinese and Russian language sites. I'd really like to see a Turkish language site, for example. What does it take to create a new one? Do you need a certain amount of Turkish users or do you have other criterion for creating those language related sites?

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: See [How can I propose a new site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site)

Comment: Incidentally, you might be interested in this: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34945/stack-overflow-in-turkish

Comment: Or if you want a site about the Turkish language, you could be interested in this: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30873/turkish-language-usage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) is where new stack exchange websites are created. The link shows the Area 51 FAQ, how to create a new site, and requirements for the site to become part of the stack exchange.

I noticed in the comments that there is already a [Turkish stack site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34945/stack-overflow-in-turkish) in the making.