# Stack Exchange website for medical questions

Tags: support, site-recommendation

1. Is there any Stack Exchange website to ask questions related to medical?
2. Is the physical fitness website including medical too?
3. Can anyone ask questions related to psychology?

Comment: Note that *personal medical advice* is off-topic just about everywhere - playing doctor on The Internet is pretty dangerous.

Comment: @Shog9: Of course you are correct, attempt at online diagnosis or trying to give specific medical advice is dangerous, but giving general medical information is fine and is similar to giving exercise or nutrition information. The problem would be would this be something that someone would have to police, and would there be any liability risk for the site and its personnel if someone crosses that line.

Comment: Example question: Why is induced ketosis an effective intervention for intractable epilepsy?

Comment: @Shog9 I'd take medical advice from stack exchange before about 99% of other sites, if it looks well vetted, at least. So I think at the margin we're doing good for the world. And we have to start somewhere - what may be small today could be an incredible resource in 5 years' - (hopefully) just like stack overflow.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To ask questions about Fitness there is [**Physical Fitness**](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/).

To ask questions about Psychology there is the [**Psychology & Neuroscience**](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/).

[**Here**](https://stackexchange.com/sites) is a list of all available Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 18):

There is also [**Medical Sciences**](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com) (currently in beta).

> …for professionals in medical and allied health fields, students of those professions, related academics, and others with a sound understanding of medicine and healthcare-related sciences.

[What topics can I ask about here?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) provides this guidance:

> What topics can I ask about here?
>
> If your question is about...
>
> - clinical guidelines
> - disease prevention and management
> - human physiology and pathophysiology
> - pharmacology
> - diagnostic and prognostic methods
> - public health
> - medical research
>
> … then this is the right place to ask.
>
> Often asked questions that are off-topic include:
>
> - medical advice for yourself or others
> - any other personal advice
> - interpretation of test results
> - treatment recommendations
> - second opinions.
>
> If your question is a request for medical advice for you or others, it is off-topic and instead should be directed to a physician. Such questions will be closed here.
>
> Questions that could be seen to be on-topic but are probably best suited elsewhere:
>
> - questions regarding psychology, psychiatry or neurology (see [Psychology.SE](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for that)
> - fundamentals of biology or chemistry (see [Biology.SE](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) or [Chemistry.SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for that)
> - questions about cooking, nutrition and diets that are not directly connected to medical treatments (see [Cooking.SE](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (Seasoned Advice) for that)
> - questions about physical fitness, athletic performance, and exercise (see [Fitness.SE](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for that)
> - questions about unreferenced claims, pseudoscience and biased results that are not specifically about medical science (see [Skeptics.SE](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for that).
> - questions about medical history (see [HSM.SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) or [History.SE](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for that).
>
> This site also requires questions to show a reasonable degree of prior research. Your question should, if possible, show what you found in your research that you don't understand or doesn't answer your question.
>
> [Please look around](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/search) to see if your question has been asked before. It’s also OK to [ask and answer your own question](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/self-answer).
>
> If your question is not specifically on-topic for MedicalSciences.SE, it may be on topic for another Stack Exchange site. If no site currently exists that will accept your question, you may [commit](https://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) to or [propose](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site) a new site at [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/), the place where new Stack Exchange communities are democratically created.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer in 2022.