# Is there a site for questions about development using SOC devices?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there a StackExchange board/webpage/whatever for Embedded Systems development, particularly for the new kinds of SOC (System on a Chip) devices that are becoming prevalent?   If not, is it possible to start one?

Comment: *is it possible to start one*: see [How can I propose a new site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76974)

Answer (score 1):

We had [Embedded Systems](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/50195/embedded-systems) in beta for a while, but it unfortunately didn't work out.

There's a new proposal up, so feel free to follow/commit to it to create another attempt at a site on this topic: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/70800/embedded-systems-programming-and-design.

In the meantime, depending on your question, it may be on topic on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) or [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).