# Hadoop Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Should questions related to Hadoop and its ecosystem (Pig, Hive, Storm, Kafka, etc.) go into Stack Overflow ?

I believe there should be a community for Hadoop users within the Stack Exchange network. Is there one? I couldn't find one in the list of Stack Exchange communities in the footer of SO. But that's just my humble opinion.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site

Answer (score 7):

Hadoop and its ecosystem seem to be on-topic on SO - Hadoop has [more than 15K questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hadoop), [Pig has 2K](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-pig), [Hive has 3K](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hive). [Storm has about 500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/storm) and [Kafka has 300](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-kafka).

However, if you believe there's a place for a dedicated site for Hadoop and its ecosystem, you could try proposing one on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).

Note: There used to be a [Big Data proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40518/big-data), but it didn't make it past the beta phase.

Answer (score 6):

[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search) would seem to be the [most logical place to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hadoop), but these would probably be questions about Hadoop itself. However, questions about the tools you need to use would also be on topic as questions about

> software tools commonly used by programmers

are explicitly on topic.

[Data Science](http://datascience.stackexchange.com) has [questions about Hadoop](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/search?q=hadoop).

[Computational Science](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com) also has [a couple of questions](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/search?q=hadoop).