# Adding links to stackexchange clones in footer?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, footer, clone

I came accross https://ask.fedoraproject.org/.

This community is based on `askbot` one of many
[Stack Exchange clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-exchange-clones/37953). I have seen the question: 
[How can I propose a new site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site) and and on their community [their rationale to stay away from proprietary software](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/33705/stackexchange-and-askfedora/).

<strike>So question is: would it be okay to add a link to that community in the footer?</strike>

As a generalization: if a community is not based on [stackexchange](/questions/tagged/stackexchange), for whatever reason (e.g. failed to be successful in [area51](/questions/tagged/area51)), can that community request to be linked in the footer?

I mean this footer:
[image: footer i'm talking about]

This question is not a feature request, but a discussion.

Comment: Does GitHub link to GitLab? Does Microsoft link to LibreOffice?

Comment: @random, does my question bother you? You are entitled to your opinion, but what is wrong with someone openly asking a question?

Comment: Why on earth would we do that? What's the benefit for Stack Exchange?

Comment: @oded, pure altruism? helping people find communities that don't exist on stackexchange network or have been turned down?

Comment: So, add hundreds of links to sites that we either don't believe can become self sustaining communities (or even are self sustaining), just because they are there?

Comment: Oh - and this feature for finding communities exists on the internet. It is called a search engine. (I realize this sounds snarky - not the intention)

Comment: @oded, @care-bare, you don't have to agree, it's all fine. You can just say `no`. You don't need to flame me down for asking the question.

Comment: We are telling you why we think this is not a good suggestion. Are you telling us we shouldn't do that?

Comment: Can someone please summarize in an answer and i'll accept it?

Comment: @oded, i think the question is a good question ([Tag:meta]), regardless of whether the part which suggests to add a link  gets implemented or not.

Comment: So you want to discuss foreign/competing sites are being allowed to request the feature of being added to the footer?

Comment: I'll just note that there are several topics where alternate Q&A websites using AskBot or OSQA are very serious competition to what SE has on offer. This sometimes creates dilemmas, see e.g. https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3102/do-we-need-version-specific-tags-for-distributions https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/what-to-do-if-your-question-was-answered-on-another-site

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The footer exists to expose sites that are part of the Stack Exchange network of sites.

You may note that the sites on in are sites that have gone out of public beta - sites that have graduated/launched (meaning that the community team believes they are self sustaining).

Not only is this footer ridiculously large *already*, but adding more sites, and sites that are outside of the network to it goes against its purpose.

That, before even deciding which sites to add. Do we add sites that directly compete with Stack Exchange sites? Do we decide by volume? What volume? How do we organize them? How do we distinguish between sites in the network and those outside? Or do we distinguish them at all? How many to add? 10? 100? All of them?

People who are looking for Q&A sites in specific topics are not likely to be using the footer anyways - the are much more likely to be using a search engine.

Comment: I actually wonder why is the footer listing the sites when the top bar already list them *all* and allow you to search

Comment: @Braiam - good point. The current footer predates the topbar by at least a year and is probably due a revisit (note that it does give a rough categorization, which the topbar doesn't).

Comment: Why would SE want to endorse sites that might have totally different codes of conduct, business models (if any), privacy policies, etc? That's sketchy.

Comment: what if everything else was the same (code of conduct, privacy policy, ...) and the only difference was: it runs on open source software therefore it is not using stackexchange.

Comment: @dnozay - find one that is exactly the same first... Even if you found one - if it isn't a part of the SE network, there is no good reason for SE to add it.

Answer (score 3):

Summary with some other comments not covered by @oded's answer.

- StackExchange is a business,
- diverting traffic away from StackExchange is not a good business model,
- therefore there would be no benefit for StackExchange,
- nobody's going to spend the time to review those communities and make sure they have same codes of conduct, privacy policy ... anything that makes them endorsable,
- legal aspect? is linking an endorsement?