# Can we post questions/answers in a native language on a Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, languages

I wanted to start a new Stack Exchange site for questions and answers related to only one country (India in my case) thereby creating a knowledge bank and inquiry site for India.

Some of the Indian people would like to ask in their native language Hindi and might want answers also in Hindi. Do Stack Exchange sites support the Hindi language and can I make such a Stack Exchange site?

Comment: Currently there is no Stack Overflow (In Hindi) proposal, but you can be the one to start it. :)

Comment: Another possible duplicate is http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76974/215590

Comment: Update: [there was such a proposal in the past](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36546/stack-overflow-in-hindi) but it did not gather enough followers, so deleted.

Comment: @PolyGeo true,  but I assumed OP here means Stack Overflow-ish site. (i.e. only programming)

Comment: I think the OP is asking about possibility to write questions and answers in Hindi language along with English not translating from English to Hindi. He said 'Some of the Indian people would like to ask in their native language Hindi and might want answers also in Hindi.' It can just be a copy-paste text in Hindi from anywhere. And I think its possible. देखा, यह हो सकता है।