# I have been wondering if there is a stack site for machine drawing or if not how to propose one

Tags: discussion

I believe machine drawing(technical drawing) is a language of its own and any engineer should master this art. As a learning engineer myself I have trouble understanding some of its conventions and I am having trouble communicating with my peers who also seem to be having the same difficulties.

I believe it would be a good idea to have a StackExchange site for technical drawing as I believe that this subject can be mastered if we are able to communicate with experienced people on this subject.
What do you guys think of this idea?
Will the site have a chance of success?
How will one propose such a site?

Answer (score 0):

Asking "why?" is not the best think you can do. It's way more constructive to:

1. Investigate which Stacks ([launched](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=launched) and [betas](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=beta)) are the best match for the kind of questions you are interested in.
2. If there's no good match, investigate [proposals](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=progress) (including [newest](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=newest) ones), if something relevant found - to participate and invest your time and effort.
3. If nothing relevant found but you still believe it is a good idea, just [propose it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site), but I'd recommend you to put some effort and discuss it beforehand, say, [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-proposal), at meta. Sometimes it looks like there's no match while it turns out not to be the case.

Speaking specifically of "Machine and technical drawing" I do recognize that this indeed could be a separate topic but it looks like that you can potentially ask at least a subset of questions you are interested in at:

- Engineering SE - http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60453/engineering
- Electrical Engineering -http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60453/engineering
- Tex, LaTex and friends - http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2148/tex-latex-and-friends
- Computer Aided Design - http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80927/computer-aided-design-cad

Comment: I have done the research, I always try to find the best books that tried to explain the laws but I did not find any, I proposed this question because I believe if this subject was more interactive it would have been more comprehensive,

Comment: If you done research than it better to move from a rhetorical statement towards more calm and reasonable discussion. You can ask something like :"Hey guys, here's the issues I'm interested in, after a bit of investigation, it looks like there's no relevant SE. I believe it should exist because a b and c. What are your thoughts on this?".