# Where can I ask a question related to social sciences?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I don't find any Social Sciences Stack Exchange. Is it possible?

Comment: Social Sciences is very broad. Traditionally it covers anthropology, sociology, social psychology, political science, and economics and possibly other fields too. Do you have any particular question in mind.

Comment: I know what social seciences are. My question regards sciology...maybe, since it is about methodology, between the other disciplines, could be asked also in a political science forum and/or others...

Answer (score 8):

“Social sciences” is a big, sprawling bunch of subjects.

I expect that there will be some social science on each of these sites:

- [Cognitive Sciences](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/)
- [Economics](http://Economics.stackexchange.com/)
- [History](http://History.stackexchange.com/)
- [History of Science and Mathematics](http://hsm.stackexchange.com)
- [Law](http://Law.stackexchange.com/)
- [Linguistics](http://Linguistics.stackexchange.com/)
- [Maths Educators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/)
- [Parenting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/)
- [Politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/)
- [Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/)

And there are various site proposals on Area 51 that you might find to be of interest:

- [Geography](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93500/geography)
- [Urban Planning](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/88933/urban-planning)

and the various pedagogy proposals including:

- [Computer Science Educators](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92460/computer-science-educators)
- [Language Learning](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82841/language-learning)

Comment: well, at any rate, it would be nice a stack exchange in sociology also.

Comment: there is also a community which deals with statistics...but the question I have in my mind would be off topic in all of these, perhaps...This is why I think it would be good a stack exchange in sociology

Comment: Please do [propose a new site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76978/164022) for sociology

Comment: This answer is pretty out of date. CogSci is renamed and all of the Area51 proposals are either dead or became actual sites. Plus some sites are missing, probably