# Stack Exchange website for cryptocurrencies in general

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

My suggestion is to add a Stack Exchange website for cryptocurrencies in general. There is just a Bitcoin website, but I have questions about cryptocurrencies in general. Maybe back when that website was started, Bitcoin was the only popular cryptocurrency, but now cryptocurrencies like Litecoin and Dogecoin are gaining popularity and they should be represented here as well. Is there a place to ask about non-Bitcoin cryptocurrencies, or would I need to propose a new site for it?

Comment: Check out [Area51.se] if you want to propose a site.

Comment: @Catija: The OP specifically requests the opportunity to create a new site, which is an adequate duplicate of [How can I propose a new site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76974/168244) If the question was posed in the form of a [tag:site-recommendation], that would be different.

Comment: @Catija: Sorry, but the question here is not about non-Bitcoin cryptocurrencies. The question is about cryptocurrencies in general, which would include Bitcoin.

Comment: @Nick: If you add the [tag:site-recommendation] tag *and* change your question to conform with that rather than to ask how to create a new site, then yes, that would be appropriate.

Comment: Yes, and then migrate bitcoin, ethereum, iota, stellar, and any other single-coin communities to it and close the single coin ones. It's ludicrous to be tending towards having a site for every different currency - we don't have a different stackoverflow for csharp, php, python, JavaScript... we have tags

Comment: So, guys, where do you ask general questions about cryptocurrencies? From this question I didn't get any conclusion

Comment: A semi-relevant Area 51 Discussions announcement from this past March: [Area 51 is no longer allowing individual blockchain, cryptocurrency, or web3 proposals](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32746/192942). That post specifically notes that we're still open to "proposals inclusive of all crypto and blockchain technologies."

Answer (score 12):

> **Note: This answer is outdated, as the site's scope was [narrowed to just Bitcoin](https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1011/proposed-timeline-for-scope-change) a few years after this answer was posted.**

---

According to the information on the Bitcoin.SE [help page](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), all questions about cryptocurrencies are welcome there.

> - a cryptocurrency or technology derived directly from Bitcoin such as Namecoin or Litecoin
> - distributed cryptocurrencies not derived directly from Bitcoin such as Ripple, Ethereum or NXT

Additionally, though there is a separate Ethereum proposal, the mods of Bitcoin welcome questions there. Additional proof on [this Area 51](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21776/ethereum-questions-are-welcome-on-bitcoin-stackexchange) discussion:

> However, I was wondering, whether you are aware that questions about all cryptocurrencies are on-topic on Bitcoin.SE (see our About). We do have a tag Ethereum with a few questions there already, and you would be welcome to add as many questions and answers as you'd like.

Subsequent [conversation in comments on an answer](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21776/ethereum-questions-are-welcome-on-bitcoin-stackexchange#comment34897_21805) there explains why the site is called Bitcoin.SE despite accepting questions about all cryptocurrencies:

> To get back to you guys about my above suggestions. I had talked with SE staff about potentially changing the name of bitcoin.se already a while ago but encountered staunch opposition. I was told that name changes had been tried before and the sites in previous attempts lost great amounts of traffic and users, all but destroying the sites. It seems that a name change will be unlikely, but you are still welcome to ask questions about Ethereum there, until you get your own site.

Comment: Maybe worth revisiting now that cryptocurrency tech has become a bigger topic? Bitcoin.SE and Ethereum.SE aren't great substitutes IMO -- those of us searching for general cryptocurrency content have to filter through a lot of posts about Solidity etc.

Comment: Revisiting what, specifically? The site name? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301373/what-is-the-point-of-having-different-sites-for-each-service-in-the-same-or-simi/306589#306589

Comment: Either a rename or a new site would be preferable to the status quo. Sounds like a rename is unlikely, so a new site would be the next best thing. I can't imagine a community named Bitcoin ever becoming a popular place to discuss crypto topics that aren't closely related to Bitcoin, such as DAG designs. Most users not interested in Bitcoin specifically just won't think to go there.

Comment: @DanielLubarov I think renaming is actually more possible than it was. In the last six months they've renamed at least 3-4 sites.

Comment: `According to the information on the Bitcoin.SE help page, all questions about cryptocurrencies are welcome there` it's not the case anymore, I don't see this passage in the Bitcoin.SE help section. What is the situation now? Where to ask questions about other cryptocurrencies?

Answer (score -2):

There was a proposal on Area 51 that didn't get enough attention.

I'm suggesting re-opening: https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26910/cryptocurrencies-should-be-re-opened-due-to-general-trends-in-the-world-at-large

Comment: @Ramhound can you please enhance you comment with the link?

Comment: You are telling me exactly what I've put in my post... Am I missing something?

Comment: According to the information on the [Bitcoin.SE](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) help page, all questions about cryptocurrencies, are welcome there.  If we already have a SE website about all cryptocurrencies I don't understand the need for another one.

Comment: Because bitcoin is huge topic in itself. Alternative cryptocurrencies deserve a dedicated space. See the explosion in the recent months...

Comment: The link is (effectively) broken now.

Comment: Agree with @MarsRobertson, the BTC is huge and all other cryptocurrencies are even bigger, they deserve a dedicated site for these two content areas to not mess each other