# Why are there SE sites for bitcoin and Ethereum, but not for blockchains / distributed ledgers?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Cf. *[Stack Exchange website for cryptocurrencies in general](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271576/stack-exchange-website-for-cryptocurrencies-in-general)*

Blockchains, or even more generally, distributed ledger technology or short DLT, is the foundational technology underneath cryptocurrencies like bitcoin and Ethereum, and about 8000 other cryptocurrencies.

**Why are there specialized SE sites for bitcoin and Ethereum, but not one to discuss the technology behind?**

<strike>I know that the bitcoin SE site welcomes other questions besides bitcoin.</strike> (see Update below) But simply nobody who wants to ask a question about the [IOTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOTA_(technology)) ledger (which uses a directed graph) will feel it's a good idea to go to a bitcoin Q&A site for asking it. This is because an expert on bitcoin might be in complete ignorance of IOTA. The term bitcoin simply does not represent the topic anymore. So the bitcoin SE site lacks attracting this audience of other blockchain and distributed ledger developers and enthusiasts.

In the sense of the bitcoin and Ethereum SE sites, we could see another 8000 sites, one for each cryptocurrency, like [Dogecoin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dogecoin) or [TRON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tron_(cryptocurrency)). That would clutter information and replicate it, and sometimes lack to replicate it, and would certainly not make it easier to find.

Similarly, we do not have an SE site specifically for [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29) programming and not a separate one for [Python](https://en.wikipedia.or/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) programming.

The Ethereum and bitcoin SE sites should be merged to a common site. Possible candidates for the new site's name and topic are:

- blockchain
- DLT (distributed ledger technology)

I argue strongly against making a site for "cryptocurrency", as the underlying technology is not only used for currencies. Think about the ledgers in development for tracking art sales or for anti-forgery of pharmaceutical products.

"blockchain" is the technology behind most distributed ledgers, but not for all. Some distributed ledgers use something else, e.g., a directed graph of blocks. That's not a blockchain. Then, distributed ledger technology is the broadest term that comes to mind and catches all the various technologies and applications.

I also argue against a separation for users of cryptocurrencies and the technology behind. An idea is to have "cryptocurrency" alongside "DLT", where cryptocurrency serves for the users of cryptocurrencies and DLT for the developers of such technology.

However, then a lot of questions on cryptocurrency would not get the attention of the true experts of these systems, the developers.

*Update 2021-02-10*:

bitcoin.se used to accept questions related to other cryptocurrencies and blockchains, but it does not anymore. See [*Bitcoin* topics](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [a discussion about the change](https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1005/).  I was misinformed from old discussions about that. Now the site's topic is what the site's name implies. However, it causes more confusion and it's more than necessary to have a blockchain.se.

Comment: Because they're the sites that were successfully proposed and started. If you think there should be others, see https://area51.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Related, maybe dupe: [Stack Exchange website for cryptocurrencies in general](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271576/stack-exchange-website-for-cryptocurrencies-in-general). (as answers there might answer your question as well)

Comment: Thanks for the link to area51. The question is rhetorical in order to spark the discussion (again). Should I move the whole question to area51?

Comment: @DanielS. about Area51 no, it's not meant for such discussion, it fits here just fine.

Comment: https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=blockchain

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating sure it's a dupe, but the discussion is pressing more than 5 years ago. And the situation has progressed, so the previous question isn't asking in a good direction anymore (pointing towards "cryptocorrency" as a name, which I strongly oppose, see my question at the end).

Comment: Well, probably, didn't put enough thought into it, and didn't vote to close.

Comment: ... to be clear, I'm personally really tired of having a ton of different sites for this. They're often tiny and, if/when the specific thing dies, the content and history is essentially lost. I'd much rather have one site for all of them but with 10-12 sites currently, I don't really know how we'd do that. This is, essentially, what I go into detail about here - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301373/what-is-the-point-of-having-different-sites-for-each-service-in-the-same-or-simi/306589#306589

Comment: Telling from the vast amount of discussions on area51 it seems clear to me that a bold person with a clear vision and enough power is required to finally change the name of bitcoin.se to blockchain.se , a step that should have been done many years ago, and for which it is still true that it should happen better sooner than later.

Comment: @DanielS. For other sites that changed their name (those I am familiar with are Health->Medical Sciences and CogSciences->Psych&Neuro) those steps were driven by the individual site Metas. Maybe a bit different in this case because other sites are potentially involved, but it seems like something to start at the Bitcoin meta anyways.

Comment: @Catija All it takes is a new policy that we will no longer open new blockchain-specific sites. I've wanted that policy for years too. Maybe it's time to have that discussion formally?

Comment: @animuson I think the concern has always been - what do we do with existing sites. Merging sites and their content is not always well-received and blending several communities into one is also complicated. If we're talking about just leaving the existing communities as-is and creating a site that's for all of the *other* blockchain-sites, that could be confusing if there's 1 hub and 10 subsites? It definitely sounds like a complex discussion to be had. :) Not averse to having it!

Comment: @DanielS. there used to be such a person, kind of, sadly he no longer works for SE and there's no replacement.

Comment: @Catija It is. But stopping the problem from ballooning more is always a good first step. It'll only be harder to solve the longer it is ignored.

Comment: @animuson this sounds oddly familiar. :/

Comment: Just go ahead and merge the whole thing. It's not like the SO JAVA and PHP communities are the same. They, as well as other tags, have their own little "communities" this can very well be the case for cryptocurrencies. They had the luxury to have seperate sites, while SO had niches from the start I guess. Ofcourse you'll upset some people, but in the end it would be easier to manage, and you would only have to have about a tenth of the elections.

Comment: What are the best steps that I can do to get a blockchain.se site, and how to do it in a way so that existing cryptocurrency sites get merged? Whom do I need to convince, and what are the best channels for addressing this audience?

Comment: @DanielS. I'm afraid that for such a big merge, you'll need to get the direct support of the [CEO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/579126/prashanth-chandrasekar). Good luck!

Comment: And having the support of (most of) the current blockchain based sites definetly helps, cc@ShadowWizardisVaccinating

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating I didn't even get past the support level. What I got back is "your discussion on Meta is already the best and only avenue available for sparking that change. Such a change would require significant discussion and buy-in from the existing communities and the Community Team, which is already aware of your discussion."
In essence, SO Team implies that community and community team don't want this change, or did I get this wrong? Btw, how to start a chat here?

Comment: @DanielS. not really "don't want" but more "don't have the resources for this". As for chat, start [here](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=meta.stackexchange.com). You can create your own room (as you have more than 100 rep), or join any of the existing chat rooms. The official room is called Tavern on the Meta, there are usually moderators and SE staff in there, but not always. Have fun! :)

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating thank you for the chat link. How much resources are we talking about here?

Comment: @DanielS lots of time discussing this internally (so time of CM's and management) and such a thing would also require unknown development time, as it's not just a simple merge.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum you can't use ( and html entities in the same link. Use either of them consistently in a single link.

Comment: @Luuklag: I think it was caused by the search engine ([DDG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DuckDuckGo)). The hit URL was `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOTA_(technology%29`, not `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOTA_(technology)`. Firefox hides the difference. The internal link at Wikipedia seems to be OK.

Comment: cont' - Reminder to self: Always click the *"Article"* link to get the proper URL.

Comment: A relevant Area 51 Discussions announcement from this past March: [Area 51 is no longer allowing individual blockchain, cryptocurrency, or web3 proposals](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32746/192942)