# Criteria for subdomains for stackexchange.com sites

Tags: support, stackexchange.com, subdomains

Based on what list of criteria or requirements does stackexchange.com create a subdomain site?

For example, they have

- android.stackexchange.com
- apple.stackexchange.com
- & so on

I'm curious to know what is the list of criteria or requirements for Stack Exchange subdomains.

or

How do they decide to create a Stack Exchange subdomain site?

Also, apart from the first question, why haven't they created something like windows.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Via voting on http://area51.stackexchange.com

Comment: As for `windows.stackexchange.com`, I think you'll find that nearly every potential question for such a site already has a home at [su].

Comment: @AlE. but I'm curious to know why they didn't create it, considering it is used by many

Comment: There was such a proposal, but it's deleted due to *the lack of interest*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The main issue here is [creating a new Q&A site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site) - the subdomain is just an implementation detail.

The process for suggesting and creating a new site is done via [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com), and explained pretty extensively in [its FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq).