# Where can I ask questions about HyperVisors?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

So I recently have been learning XenServer VMWare Hyper-V KVM and its been a ride! But each program/hypervisor would have different locations for questions. Like KVM/XenServer I might ask in Unix n Linux, but Hyper-V in super user/server fault and VMWare I am not even sure, its its own beast, probably server-fault.

Where would you recommend I ask hyper-visor related questions?

Comment: Edited the question to fit the answer. Otherwise, it's dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) is a reasonable place to ask most of these questions. But if you're using VMs for development purposes, there's no reason not to ask on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

As always, find the folks doing what you're doing and ask them; don't worry about finding the single perfect site for your question, it's quite possible multiple sites would welcome it from one of their own.

Comment: Fair enough it's just such a broad complicated topic but then again server fault has a broad purpose