# Where can I ask SAP related questions of mine?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

- Which Stack Exchange site should I use?
- Also is there a proposal on the way for creation of a SAP related site?

Comment: [How can I propose a new site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76974/307988)

Comment: Giving an example question would really help here (and what is SAP?), as it is it's not really clear what you're looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in)

Comment: I don't think that is a good dupe as it fails to mention [SF] and [SU] both of which could have SAP related questions checked at them.

Answer (score 6):

> Which Stack Exchange site should I use?

I would imagine that it would depend upon what kind of SAP related question it is. It could got to Stack Overflow for programming related stuff, Server Fault for backend servery kinda stuff. Possibly Super User IDK.

If I recall correctly, you will be paying lots of $ and several body parts for SAP support. Why don't you ask them for help instead?

> Also is there a proposal on the way for creation of a SAP related site?

Go to [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) and look.

Comment: "If I recall correctly, you will be paying lots of $ and several body parts for SAP support." -- if you teach SAP at a university, you might not get proper SAP support.

Answer (score 1):

If your SAP related questions are about programming, then you can use StackOverflow.

If you use ABAP, then you can tag your question with "abap".

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/abap