# A site on women's issues

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there a site on the Stack Exchange network to ask and answer questions relating to women's issues?

Comment: Can you give an example? I ask because I do not believe there's any site in the Stack Exchange network dedicated to that topic but specific questions might find a home in existing stacks depending on the details.

Comment: Health SE and physical fitness SE is there. But I think there is no such specific site for women only issues. Anyway you can propose one on area51

Comment: Probably depends on the particular issues. There are sites to discuss politics or law issuse in general. Not generally gender oriented.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I propose a new site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site)

Comment: If you want to see if a site exists then search for one yourself. If it does not exist and you want to propose it go to [area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com) to propose it; here is not the right place for site proposals or searches.

Comment: @John Actually, MSE is entirely the right place to ask "where should I ask questions about X". This question is too *broad* in its current form, but it's completely appropriate here, as are the other 1469 questions tagged [tag:site-recommendation].

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, there is not. There were several site proposals related to this in the past, e.g. [Feminism & Women's Rights](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/103283/feminism-womens-rights) (now deleted), but they didn't gather enough support and thus had been all closed. The best action for you to take, then, is to support such proposals when they exist, and also attempt to spread the word. Then, if the proposal fails, you can make another one, however, [these proposals have, so far, been running into barriers](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25495/why-do-proposals-for-a-feminism-stackexchange-keep-failing).

As for sites that currently exist it really depends on what you're asking about:

- [Medical Science](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/) exists for medical issues.
- [Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) can be used for certain questions about women's rights in the workplace.
- [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) is similar but in an academic context.
- [Politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/) can be used for concrete questions about government actions and politics.
- [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/) can be used for purely legal questions.
- And [many other sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295721/inquiring-about-a-site-to-ask-and-answer-questions/295723#comment959477_295723) - For the most part, any questions you may have about gender-specific issues in a particular topic are generally welcome on the site dedicated to that topic provided you stick to that site's posting guidelines, so check out [the full list](https://stackexchange.com/sites).

But be sure to take the tour on each of those sites first, and browse existing similar questions, to make sure your questions are appropriate for those sites.

Comment: There goes my answer then! These were top of my list, but I'd also include Personal Finance & Money, the various religious sites, even Expatriates, Personal Productivity, Mathematics Educators or Parenting (depending on the question).