# Why don't we have a social sciences site?

Tags: feature-request, site-recommendation, site-proposal

I am a graduate in biology and have worked on a thesis in the humanities titled 'Social science in the age of biology'. It discusses how biologists adopt different approaches to questions pertaining to human behaviour and organisation of society. It piqued my interest in the social sciences.

I have now begun to study some of the works in the social sciences independently and am frustrated by the lack of learning resources online. Time and again, I feel the need for guidance. I am unable to enroll in a university for personal reasons.

Stack Exchange provides a great platform for guided online learning.
Is it possible to create a site where questions belonging to the social sciences can be addressed?

Comment: Social psychology, and sometimes sociology, are sometimes [on-topic](https://cogsci.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=sociology) at https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/. If your question is heavily oriented to biology there is https://biology.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Obligatory reference: *[435: Purity](http://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/435:_Purity)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to create a site where questions belonging to the social sciences can be addressed?

Sure. [Propose one at Area 51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site).

---

**But wait!**

> Time and again, I feel the need for guidance.
>
> ---
>
> Stack exchange provides a great platform for guided online learning.

Stack Exchange sites are generally not fitting well for tutoring or guidance with learning. So your Area 51 proposal will fail along the overall policies setup for SE sites.