# SE about general research design and methology

Tags: discussion, area-51, site-recommendation

As far as I have seen, there are only field-specific SE's for questions regarding research methods.

I agree, that it makes sense to ask question about research design and methodology in context of the field of study.

But when studying research methods and research design in preparation for future studies, I am facing a domain of it's own. The literature about research methods is mostly not bound to any field (with some exceptions of really field-specific methods).

This concerns many questions regarding (among others):

- Interview design and interview practice, survey design, coding practices, instruments and instrument design, item design
- Adequate sample sizes, anonymizing data and sensitive data, proper Evaluation
- Validity, reliability, economy of testing
- Research ethics and unethical research design

Where would those questions be asked, if not bound to any specific field of study? If there is none, would it make sense to have one like "Research Methods"?

**Update:**

As I can see there are two pages close to the described above - [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) and [Openscience (Area 51)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/90201/open-science).

While as I can see, Academia is related a lot regarding every day questions of an academic - ranging from juridical and administrative to professional career related questions.

Open science looks very focused on strategies and QA to make Science more accessible in general, like open journals, licensing, publishing and documentation/transparency of research.

Both sites focus in my opinion on other content than research methodology. If nobody has an interest **against** a proposal, I would tend create one at Area51.

Comment: Wouldn't this be [academia.se]?

Comment: That was my very first SE page to go but it seems that there are also lots of questions regarding every day problems of an academic, such as juridical, administrative and professional carreer related questions. In my opinion research methodology is such a huge (and relevant) topic that a mixup with academia would blow the scope of the SE page. (IMO)

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site

Comment: So you think I should propose a new site? I am not 100% sure about that yet.

Comment: There's never a reason not to propose a new site. It doesn't need to be discussed here first. Just make the proposal, then it can be properly vetted on Area 51.