# Where to ask questions on architecture?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where can I ask questions on Architectural Engineering? I could not find any site related to it.

I even checked Area 51 if there is a proposal for this, but there isn't. Does the site exist anywhere?

Architecture is a common field. It should be there.

Answer (score 1):

Some of your questions might be [on-topic on Engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) or [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/architectural-engineering) (they have a tag on that subject).

If there is a field or subject that isn't covered by any site in the network, feel free to [propose a new site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76974/245360).

Comment: I just want to ask questions on structural engineering of buildings and structures. Basically reasoning on design choices.

Comment: Do these sites fit? If not, why not?

Comment: I think it should have to be separate. Architecture is a broad field. Most of the tags, though not much, overlap with other aspects of engg like Mechanical, Industrial design