# Isn't there a section for the Persian/Farsi language?

Tags: support, site-proposal

I just wanted to ask if there is a section for the Persian language OR if there isn't one, do you have any plan on creating such a section?

Because I saw most of Persian questions asked on "English.stackexchange", and I did not find such a specific place for that.

Comment: There's none; check [area51.se] for any existing proposals or create a new one.

Comment: This should use the [tag:support] tag rather than the [tag:feature-request] tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no Stack Exchange site to answer that question. You can create such a section by heading over to [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com) where you can propose a new section (you have to confirm your email address beforehand though).

I suggest you read their [FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) which takes you through the steps and should have all the information you need.

Also see the [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site) linked in the comments to your question, which goes through the steps of getting your sites onto Area 51.

However if you have a specific question in mind, and it would be acceptable on [English SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/), check their [on topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) list and feel free to ask there.

Also there is an [Language Learning SE](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com) which may also be useful depending on the questions you wish to ask.