# What are the launching criteria for a new SE website?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, graduating-sites

So, I was browsing Stack Overflow's [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) website and I found this:
[What is Stack Overflow's goal?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254770/what-is-stack-overflow-s-goal)

I did read the answers and the [first one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254973/7205123) caught my eye:

> SO no longer meets the standards that SE sets for a new site to be launched.

I was wondering, what are these standards?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I propose a new site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site)

Comment: @RobertColumbia where are these standards/criteria mentioned in the linked question/answer?

Comment: @RobertColumbia Not a duplicate. This one asks about the criteria about launching an existing proposal; that's for creating new proposals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see these standards if you visit a proposal on [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/), for example the recently launched [Quantum Computing](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/106955/quantum-computing). You see that the 'expected' number of answers to a question is 2.5, not 1.5 (or lower) as mentioned in the Meta Stack Overflow question you linked to. 'Launched' in this context is the same as 'graduation' from a beta site to a full-grown site in the Stack Exchange network.

However, the [only standard that (recently) mattered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/295232) is the number of questions per day. If the 'critical mass' of 10 questions per day is reached consistently, and the Community Team feels the site can moderate itself (including holding a successful election) it will be launched even if the site is lacking in some of the other key figures.

Comment: Note that some sites falter on questions per day but perform excellently on the four other statistics. Much of these are still in beta.