# Why are there no SPECIFIC augmented/virtual reality tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I know augmented reality (AR) specifically comes under virtual reality (VR) which comes under user interface, HOWEVER companies like Google/Apple are releasing specific augmented reality libraries like ARcore & virtual reality headsets exist now (specifically branded as virtual reality headsets).

It would be nice to be able to have a category for this, maybe even a separate stack site. The tech is on the cusp of becoming "mature" after all, with multiple companies striving to create platforms to support it (Microsoft/Google/Samsung/Oculus/LG all have some sort of VR/AR offering) along with game development companies creating their OWN VR/AR stacks as such.
Having to search under various different tags for someone who specializes not in user interface but in virtual reality interfaces is confusing right?

Or am I as usual thinking Stack Overflow supports a use case that is actually accidental and should be burninated or whatever?

Comment: I am not sure whether you want to propose a VR site or propose a VR tag on a site?

Comment: Are you asking for a [vr] tag? Because I wouldn't call that specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But there *are* tags for AR/VR devices:

- [Oculus Rift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oculus)
- [Google Glass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-glass)

and libraries:

- [ARKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arkit)
- [ARCore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arcore)

(next to generic [augmented reality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/augmented-reality) and [virtual reality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-reality) tags).

Stack Overflow is focused on practical problems people face while developing AR/VR experiences, not for broad, implementation-agnostic discussions about AR/VR. Those questions generally aren't a good fit for Stack Exchange's Q&A format, but if you still think you can make a decent site out of it, visit [How can I propose a new site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site)

Comment: i guess i'm still confused by the tags functionality then - what i'm wondering is why don't all these types of tags get pulled into the augmented/virtual reality tag automatically?

Comment: Let's say I'm very proficient with ARKit but not with ARCore. How will I efficiently find questions I can answer? If I browse the [augmented-reality] tag, I need to skip half of the questions.

Comment: i guess i have a different mindset then - someone who's proficient with ARKit will(in my mind) naturally seek to be proficient with ARCore, because who is hiring someone to build AR apps ONLY on one platform - apart from very small companies? thanks for explaining

Answer (score 0):

For some questions [ComputerGraphics.SE](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) may be the best choice. They even have a virtual-reality tag. But be sure to read ther help center on whether your question is truly on-topic:

> **Computer Graphics Stack Exchange** is for computer graphics researchers and programmers.
>
> Topics that are usually a good fit for this site include:
>
> - Questions about math related to computer graphics,
> - Questions about a specific graphics programming or debugging problem,
> - Questions about a specific graphics API,
> - Questions about a specific graphics algorithm or concept.
>
> If your question generally covers (one of) these topics, then you’re in the right place to ask your question!
>
> However, some questions are still off-topic, although they might fit into the above criteria.
>
> - Questions asking for off-site resources including books, tools and tutorials are off-topic as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Also, the other sites may remove their content, which makes the question here useless for future visitors. Instead, ask about the specific problem you have.
> - The same applies to questions asking for software recommendations. You may ask such questions on Software Recommendations Stack Exchange, but please first read over their Help Center and quality guidelines.
> - Questions about how to use (a feature of) modeling software are off-topic here, but may be suitable to Super User. Questions specific to Blender may even be asked on Blender Stack Exchange. Again, please have a look into their Help Centers before asking.
> - Questions about Computer Vision are off-topic, except where it overlaps with computer graphics. As there is a significant part of overlap between these two topics, the line is blurry. Computer Vision questions unrelated to computer graphics may be suitable to Signal Processing Stack Exchange.