# Why is there no SE on relationship advice?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I've seen multiple SE on a large amount of subjects and I think that is great, however, I've come to realized that there is no SE on relationship questions.

I think there is much to share in those subject, where people could explain their experiences and give their advice on problems. I know there is an Interpersonal Skills which could be used, to a certain extent, for those kind of questions, however, I think a SE applied to relations with SO would be more adequate.

If it's because there would not be a way to ensure when an answer can be accepted or not, could you please suggest me to another SE where I could find questions related to that subject ?

Comment: One has been proposed, https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44577/relationships-and-dating seems it did not do well

Comment: There once was one actually, and it tanked (if not quite epicly so). It can be a very...problematic topic.

Comment: Could some of it be covered by [interpersonal.se]?

Comment: Since it's been 5 years it was tried, maybe will it have more success if we retry no ? I'm still new to the process of new SE...

Comment: I looked around Interpersonal Skills, but I see no questions related to some of mines. I just thought they were not the place where those kind of questions will be well received

Comment: hey @luisarcher! I moderate Interpersonal Skills as well: It's basically a site for questions and answers about the behaviour you use to interact with other people/people use to interact with each other. I'm not sure what your specific question is, but you could always try the Sandbox on our meta or our main chatroom if you'd want some confirmation first :)

Comment: @Tinkeringbell thanks for the information, I'll be sure to check it out!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I propose a new site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Interpersonal Skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/) is actually quite a good fit for this type of thing. [Almost 500 questions on romantic/intimate relationships](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relationships) have been asked since the site's conception, and they typically receive fairly good answers. In my time on IPS, I certainly haven't seen any reason to not bring up that sort of issue. I've done as much myself on at least one occasion, and was pleased with the results. I attribute part of that success to [the extremely strict answer requirements](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3266/102) (e.g. backing up answers with personal experience) that we've built up over the past couple of years, as well as the community's dedication to enforcing these standards.

In response to your final paragraph: The subjectivity inherent in these sort of questions is present everywhere on IPS, but it's very much [the good sort of subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). Folks can still accept whichever answer helps them the most in a given situation, and the system seems to work quite well.

Comment: It might be worth noting that IPS is **really** strict on backing up answers with personal experience or external sources. See [here for more](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3271/21067). Also, we have a [Sandbox](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3129/21067) to help people write their question before posting them on main.