# Should there be a colorimetry site?

Tags: discussion, area-51, specific-proposal

I wonder where to place question specific to the mathematics of colors (aka "colorimetry"). Some people at the photography site think such questions don't fit there. If so where should they be asked? Should there be a "colorimetry" site?

See also: [Where to ask color-related questions if not in Photography?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6959/where-to-ask-color-related-questions-if-not-in-photography)

Comment: Propose it here: https://area51.stackexchange.com/.  That said, it seems very specific; colorimetry questions can be asked on the Math site.

Comment: area51...are you saying the topic is very exotic (read: special)? Isn't all the stack exchange about meeting specialists? Asking in math: Many problems are not about mathematical formulas; there's more behind... So it seems I don't have a good answer yet. I'll post my new question in photography and see what happens...

Comment: OK, so far I have 5 down-votes, but I must admit that I did not find https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site before. In addition the answer given below is much better than the generic advice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Colorimetry is probably too small to be its own site. It's pretty specialized, and overlaps several existing sites. It looks to me like the question you posted probably fits best in [the computer graphics site](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color-science) under [color-science](/questions/tagged/color-science).

Comment: One problem is if you search the list of sites using a keyword like "color", the site suggested is not listed as `color-science` is a tag within the site (which does not cause a search hit).

Comment: @U.Windl Kel Solaar, who gave you that amazinginly excellent answer to the last question, posts on Computer Graphics as well.

Answer (score 6):

@Rockwalrus' answer is better than suggesting Graphic Design, since there's only [a few questions](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4205/photoshop-relative-colormetric-conversion-inconsistent), and they're not about Mathematics. There are [more than 500](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bvisible-light%5D+math*) on Physics.SE concerning visible light and math; but you'll have to word it carefully to make it a physics question.

Comment: Just in case: My new question was: https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/113243/82107

Comment: Scott's very knowledgeable, you *might* go OT there in a day or two; they'll help you improve your question first, but it's a stretch as to how it's **directly** related to photography. Back to my answer above, does [this answer on Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/419628/170832) completely answer your question?, the other answers provide a bit more help. Just use the "CIE L\*u\*v\*" formula.

Comment: @U.Windl I agree that Physics could be a good match, but as Rob says, you will need to be careful. Physics has a strict policy against "how do I calculate this" and "check my work" questions. It's primarily to fend off homework questions, but it also covers stuff that isn't actual homework.