# Corona StackExchange

Tags: discussion, meta

Now that the world is locked up there are questions all over the Internet, but i could not find one single spot for answer threads. This is not only medical but also questions on how to organize specific things now that in many countries need to work from home. When I watch the news I hear people say "i dont know" "i dont know" and "i dont know". E.g. now that all restaurants are closed healthcare organisations dont know where to obtain food from. Now that all schools are closed it is unkown if children are allowed to play outside. Now that most companies work remotely 100% lots of sysadmins need to organize a lot of things that were not in place yet, so lots of questions.

It would be an idea to create a public temporary Corona StackExchange for these kind of questions, since this is the primary place at least for me to ask questions and lookup information.

Comment: There is a health stack exchange site.

Comment: @Helmar I think this is multi-disciplinary, not only medical. E.g. "no bus will drive anymore for the coming weeks to my village, is a taxi my only option". "My country X is in complete lockdown am i allowed to xxx" etc

Comment: https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/ seems to cover much of this.

Comment: I think all site proposals should follow that process, no matter what. Because that process guarantees you'll have the experts that want to and can answer (your) question(s) on that topic. if you haven't covered that you only added yet another place with lots of questions, but no reputable answers.

Comment: @rene yes its a business decision to create a new process e.g. "we now introduce a hotfix process that bypasses the OTAP and can be deployed to P directly"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I propose a new site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site)

Comment: If we *do* do this, I propose the site name Coronoverflow.

Comment: Why COVID-19? Not Ebola, SARS, AIDS, ...? There have been/will be lots of epidemies, each with many of the same society symptoms.

Comment: "now that all restaurants are closed healthcare organisations dont know where to obtain food from." I only wish hospital food came from restaurants!!! During my recent hospitalizations (USA), it was more like it came from dumpster-diving.

Comment: "on how to organize specific things now" Use https://workplace.stackexchange.com/ or https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/ for some of these questions.

Comment: @vonbrand because it's an WHO official pandemic. When 9/11 happened some 2000 people died. 2 days ago 793 people died in 1 day, yesterday 600some in Italy alone.
There is no central source of verified information only news outlets who for the most part post clickbait articles. A sane place is required.

Comment: @altu: And an SE site where anonymous people can write whatever is that sane place? No. Listen to medical professionals. Not to a random dude on the internet.

Comment: The biggest hackathon of the world just happend this weekend see https://www.bundesregierung.de/breg-de/themen/coronavirus/wir-vs-virus-1731968 - it would have been very good to have a site to have a structured discussion. I am astonished how hostile the stackexchange community is towards the idea of supporting the cooperation of people accross different knowledge realms.

Comment: This is a good question. Hostile down voting is silly. I am not sure the concept of down voting is altogether reasonable at all.

Answer (score 15):

While it's an interesting idea, I disagree. This would be setting the precedent for more flash-in-the-pan sites in the future. Do we make a site for the US 2020 election? For the Olympics? I'm sure every big event has a lot of questions around it, but that doesn't mean we need a site for them.

Instead, I'd advise taking your question to one of the existing sites. [Politics.SE](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covid-19-virus), [Travel.SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covid-19-virus), [MedicalSciences.SE](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covid-19) and more have their own [covid-19-virus](/questions/tagged/covid-19-virus) tags for these questions.

If you're hoping to read questions across the network about COVID-19, your best bet is probably a userscript that'll pull questions from these cross-site tags for easy browsing.

Comment: This is not flash-in-the-pan. This never happened before. This is uncharted.

Comment: @edel I'm not referring to Corona virus there, but rather the SE site you're asking to create. What happens in a year or two when all of this has died down? Will the site still be used or generate any traffic? By "flash-in-the-pan site," I mean that the site will be essentially temporary.

Comment: Yes, its temporary because never before every country in the world is in lockdown modus. This is not planned like Olympics or elections.

Comment: You make a good point that this does have a bigger impact @edel, but you still haven't explained why the existing sites aren't already more than up to the task of fielding your questions. What purpose would a COVID-19 site serve that the existing sites don't already?

Comment: My country is now on lockdown as is the country of the 3rd party development team. Based on the chats in slack, whatsapp but also watching tv there are only questions and sometimes repeated. There is however nowhere one single spot to refer to for answers to these questions. That should be a single url to communicate. Every company is making their own internal FAQs and every nation and every tv show but there is not a single point to go to and refer to.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear about your situation @edel, but why do you think that StackExchange should be the place for the site you're imagining? Reading the type of questions you're thinking of in the comment above, they seem to be extremely location specific. I know the US has [the CDC](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-nCoV/index.html) which acts essentially as you describe. Perhaps your government has a similar site where you can find these answers?

Comment: I think that is the point of the stack Exchanges: to be above the local gazillion forums and websites. The benefit of stackexchange is that correct answers get voted to the top + it's over-countries-same-questions.

Comment: I'm glad that you have confidence in the StackExchange model to give correct answers @edel, but that's really not enough of a reason to build a new SE site. I'd take a look at [the link rene gave](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345158/corona-stackexchange/345159#comment1156603_345158) on what's required and expected in a new SE site.

Comment: @edelwater, there have been lots of epidemical outbreaks (SARS, AIDS, the Ebola scare, ...). This isn't exactly unheard of, in a short (or not so short) while it will be old hat, past history.

Comment: God some of you people are so dense. Why would you NOT create a coronavirus subdomain? It's a global pandemic. This isn't about computers who have no emotions or lifetime. This is about people. The last global pandemic was Yersinia Pestis. They didn't have computers back then. We have them and don't use the infrastructure already in place because of some snobs?

Comment: @altu I see this is something you care a lot about. I'd advise making your argument in the form of an [Area 51 proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/). If you do so and find no one willing to research/answer/moderate such a site, then it would likely be better that such a site didn't exist at all. Without a strong community backing it would become an unmoderated, unresearched mess that's almost as bad as the "clickbait articles" you talk about. On the other hand, if you make the proposal and find overwhelming community support, I'd love to see how it works in beta.