# Why does Stack Exchange not have an expat website?

Tags: support, stack-exchange

We, as expats for example in Germany, face a lot situations which require asking questions and seeking answers. We do in private groups, on Facebook, or search on Google. However, I believe if we have a Stack Exchange or Stack Overflow-like one, it would be magnificent.

Why does Stack Exchange not have an expat website?

Answer (score 11):

Visit the [list of all Stack Exchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#name) and search there, or Google “Stack Exchange Expatriates”, and you’ll find the [**Expatriates Stack Exchange** site](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) which already exists.

Alternatively, you could search if a site proposal exists on [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/).
*Alternatively*, the [global tag search](https://stackexchange.com/filters) would have provided you with some sites where expatriates-related tags exist; e.g. [Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is another site to consider — it depends on what your question is.

If no site about the topic exists, anyone can [propose their own site on Area 51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76974/289905).