# Is there a community where I can ask questions about Google Hangouts?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there a community where I can ask questions about Google and it's products?
I tried searching on the list of Stack Exchange Websites and that came out with no result. If there isn't one, how can I suggest that one be created?

I had a doubt about a possible bug(?) in Google Hangouts. It has happened to me for some days now. I am an active Hangouts user. Though I prefer to read my Hangouts messages from Gmail itself. Sometimes, I see my friend active and I message them with a usual "hi". But as soon as I do that and close the small Hangouts tab that opens in the bottom-right of Gmail, Hangouts suddenly shows that the person I tried to contact was "active 15 minutes ago". The time is always 15 minutes. Not less, not more. I wanted to know why that happens.

UPDATE (23-10-2020) : @Ollie has generously suggested [Webapps Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) to ask my question.

Comment: That would be highly dependable on what question about what google product you want to ask.  I suggest you include (a summary of) your question here.

Comment: @Luuklag, I have already added a summary. Hope that helps?

Comment: To request a new SE site, see https://area51.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @RyanM - thanks! I think that answers the rest of the question as well.

Comment: There is a FAQ post: [How can I propose a new site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76974) Although I am not sure how active Area51 is these days and whether creating a new site would be really feasible. But there are certainly many users around here who have more experience with Area51 and are able to tell you more about that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try asking your question over at [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/).  They have the [google-hangouts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-hangouts) tag there.