# Is there a site for Greek language?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, site-proposal

Could you tell me if there is any site for Greek language? I can't seem to find one, but maybe I am just not good at searching.

Comment: No such site, however you can learn how to suggest a new site to be added to Stack Exchange [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site).

Comment: Last time I suggested something I was buried alive :))) But thank you, I will have a look.

Comment: Ok, I went to the moon and back. I can't propose a new site if I don't have a supporting community. If any community who loves Greek reads this, please, do let me know!!!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Latin Language Stack Exchange accepts questions about classical Greek: [Policy on Greek questions](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358/policy-on-greek-questions)

There is no site in the network for modern Greek, but if you have an existing organization or community ready to form a new Stack Exchange site, you can make a proposal on [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @ Glorfindel: Thank you. Pity, we don't have Greek. Maybe it will come. I am thrilled there is one for French :)

Comment: @fev don't build your hopes too high, these days SE don't focus on new sites anymore.

Comment: Good you tell me, I will try to look elsewhere then.

Comment: There have been proposals for a Greek site before. All have failed.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask questions about Greek literature on [Literature SE](https://literature.stackexchange.com/). (In fact, there is much overlap between existing language sites and Lit SE because Lit SE accepts questions about the [meaning of passages in literature](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1127/5747).)

Here is an example of a question that asks about Greek (though the work only has a few words in Greek):

- [Meaning of Greek concepts on omniscience in Amélie Nothomb's Soif](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/14742/5747)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be relevant, as language is not literature, nor is literature the language.

Comment: @Nij This answer is based on my observations with ELU and Lit; many of the questions on ELU are on topic for Lit.