# On which SE should I ask questions about B corps?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'd like to ask a question about B corps on one of the SE sites. More specifically, I'd like to ask about companies that once had a B corp certification, but lost it for some reason. I'm planning on asking whether there is an overview of such companies (including Etsy), and to what extent it is known how and why these firms lost their B corp status.

On which SE site -- if any -- can I ask this question?

Comment: can you articulate what a B Corp is - I'm assuming it's specific to a particular country? Actually - probably not relevant for this meta post. It's obviously something financial

Comment: @RoryAlsop It's a kind of certificate for certain corporations that are performing well according to a number of indicators, like the environment and the wellbeing of workers. More about it can be found over here: https://bcorporation.net/ .

Comment: Maybe [Law SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/search?q=B+corp)?  Check out the [corporate-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/corporate-law) tag.

Comment: @Ollie Hmm maybe, yes. I'm slightly hesitant about this SE though because a B Corp is not a legal entity, it's a certificate by a private organization. A benefit corporation *is* a legal entity. The two are often mixed up. Here's an explanation: https://bcorporation.net/faq-item/whats-difference-between-certified-b-corp-and-benefit-corporation#:~:text=The%20B%20Corp%20Certification%20is,an%20LLC%20or%20a%20corporation.

Comment: It seems to be a question about which site to ask [about corporate culture, specifically "B Corp Certification"](https://bcorporation.net/about-b-lab), as such we don't seem to offer such a site; or one about "Business" in general. --- While it's not a simple process it's possible to "[Propose a New Site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76978/282094)".

Comment: As described, your question does not belong on any Stack Exchange site, whether existent or not, because of how enormously broad it is. A question of the type "give me examples of the category X and why the objects belong in that category" is far too vague.

Comment: @Nij I disagree. I don't think there are that many companies that lost their B corp status, so in that sense the question is quite focused. Furthermore, a number of SE sites have a "big-list" tag, so they facilitate questions with multiple (correct) answers. Finally, one can also answer the question by describing the reason(s) why these companies generally lose their B corp status, thereby circumventing the need to name specific examples.