# Why is it so important to restrict questions to being 'on-topic' that some questions can't be asked anywhere on SE?

Tags: support, scope

For example, a question about physics education is seemingly not on-topic on Physics. But there is no Physics Education nor Science Education, so it seems there is nowhere on SE that a question about physics education would be on-topic. So why not make room for such a question on Physics?

Answer (score 11):

The community of each site decides its scope.

It does not accept any and all questions loosely related to its topic because it needs to be able to have enough volunteers amongst  its users to provide answers to around 80% of questions asked. Sometimes the scope of a site is expanded slightly, and at other times it may be tightened slightly.  This can happen as a community's interests and volunteered resources drift over time.

If you see a gap between the scopes of the existing Stack Exchange sites, think you can help support a new one being created to cover it and know of an exisiting group of people that want to join you, then you can do that at [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/).   [How can I propose a new site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site) describes the process.