# Where to ask questions about KaiOS?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to ask a question related to [KaiOS](https://www.kaiostech.com/), a popular  mobile operating system.

I noticed that [Windows Phone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Phone) already has [its own site on Stack Exchange](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/).

Is there a site in Stack Exchange network that might be appropriate for KaiOS questions? Adding a new site just for that seems extreme.

I tried [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1657965/kaios-doesn-t-sync-gmail-contacts). I made [a proposal here](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1032/could-this-site-change-its-title-to-retro-and-micro-computing).

Comment: What kind of questions do you want to ask? Stack Overflow would work for programming questions for instance.

Comment: @RobertLongson I linked an example question which definitely doesn’t fit stack overflow.

Comment: Based on the moderator's comment there it would seem you'd need to propose a site.

Comment: KaiOS is off topic for SU. Unfortunately I don't think there's a good fit for feature phones and other niche mobile platforms on SE right now

Comment: @Journeyman I’m making a proposal to change retro computing to retro and micro computing or potentially just allow a kaios tag.

Comment: It's not a great fit there as a modern os. I kinda often wonder if rescoping windows phone might be an option

Comment: William, a [similar question about the predecessor](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/6253/questions-on-firefox-os-to-post-here-or-in-firefox-os-enthusiasts) answered by the moderator; SU, programming on SO. Not sure why the other moderators don't favor it, change of policy?

Comment: Well windows RT is a essentially desktoppy os. We don't do phones in general

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I propose a new site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site)

Comment: @Luuklag no, this question here is asking for site recommendation. If there is no such site, it should get proper answer saying this and explaining why.

Comment: I have never ever heard of KaiOS before now, but [apparently yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KaiOS): *"In market share study results announced in May 2018, KaiOS beat Apple's iOS for second place in India"*. It just shows how vast the technology field is, outside of our small bubbles (say, [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code)).

Comment: I am now using Reddit the market share is to small for a separate site unfortunately.