# What is the best Stack Exchange community to ask about bullying?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have been looking for a community that deals with bullies and bullying and the victims of bullying. I cannot find one, and I thought that it would be best suited to be discussed under "Parenting" or "Psychology" if it does not deserve its own community.

Where can I find the correct community to discuss/post about bullying? Or can one be created? Who can create one, and what does it cost?

Comment: Wow. That is very hostile downvoting. Not sure why though - please enlighten me?

Comment: Downvotes might be because people think you mean to create whole site dedicated to bullying, which isn't good idea as we already have enough sites, just depends what aspect of bullying you want to ask about. I'll edit the title.

Comment: Bullying is a very vast topic. Trust me - I was a victim of severe bullying, and I am the father of a kid that was bullied. The nightmares my wife and I went through to get my child to go back to school was intense! The effect the bullying had on my formative years were extremely painful and stunting my personal growth and self-confidence. It took my more than a decade after my school years to become confident and strong again. There are many kinds of bullying, and not a single way to treat any of them, because people are all different. The reasons for bullying are all different. Oh well. :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We have a [Parenting site](https://parenting.stackexchange.com) that has a [bullying](/questions/tagged/bullying) tag

> Helping your child deal with being bullied or dealing with your child who is exhibiting bullying behavior.

We've also a [Workplace site](https://workplace.stackexchange.com) with that [same tag](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bullying) for

> Questions relating to abusive / intimidating behaviour in the workplace

[Jon Custer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/405150/jon-custer) points out that [Interpersonal skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com) also has a bullying tag

> When someone is hurt or frightened by someone who is bigger or more powerful, and is trying to force them to do something that they do not want to do.

There are questions about bulling on the [Psychology site](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/search?q=bullying) but there's no bullying tag. Instead they seem to use the [human-factors](/questions/tagged/human-factors) or [social-psychology](/questions/tagged/social-psychology) tags.

As always check out the site's help centres to check your question would be on-topic.

If you want to propose your own site there's [a process for that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site) but you really need a community of people who can get that site off the ground with you. Creating a new site costs nothing.

Comment: To be comprehensive, also note that RPG SE accepts questions about bullying in the context of tabletop RPGS (or LARPing). The appropriate tag would probably be [problem-players] or [problem-gm].