# How can I more easily access all content related to a specific subject?

Tags: discussion, support

[Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) is a major distribution with a community you can find [here](https://stackexchange.com/sites). If I'm gathering information about **Debian** related topics/solutions, I need to jump between 3 sites on SE.

I often look at [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) and not all of the information is useful because much of the content on the site is not related to Debian. Sometimes I find solutions on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) and  [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) but I have the same issue - much on the site is unrelated to Debian and I'd rather just see content about Debian in one place.

Of course I know about https://www.debian.org/ and many solutions I  find elsewhere.

If someone could explain or give me some hints - **why it is better to jump between several sites** to find questions about a single subject rather than have a site for each subject where all questions exist?

Understanding this would help me know if I should [propose a new site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site) instead.

Comment: Debian is on-topic at [unix.se], with over [14k questions there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debian).

Comment: There once was an attempt to create a debian site: https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/12165

Comment: @Catija: <tone class="cheerful / possitive / kudos">post alchemist</tone>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At its core, your issue seems to be one that we recognize but don't know how to address. It shouldn't require creating a new site for smaller and smaller subject areas since there are benefits to being part of a larger site - but there are areas that we specialize either by subject or question type that lead to users in your situation - having to search for answers on multiple sites or just join multiple sites to answer questions related to their area of expertise.

While this is something many people here have gotten used to and may not even think about any more, I think it's worth understanding that being used to it doesn't mean it's the best way to handle things.

### Questions on sites exist only on one site...

... unless manually asked and answered on the other sites. While it'd be amazing to have all questions related to Debian in one place - or any subject for that matter - doing so is not part of our current architecture. The only current solution is to use the existing system and rely on multiple sites for your answers or try to create a new site. Unfortunately, the new site would be starting from nothing and all of the questions and answers would have to be created from scratch.

Since the questions that already exist on AU, SO and U&L, are on topic where they were asked, we would not migrate them to a new site for a specific subject. Questions can be on topic on multiple sites with no issues, so we're not going to tell these established sites, "Hey, you can't allow Debian questions any more because there's a Debian site now".

As such, even if we didn't close a proposal as a duplicate of an existing site (which is the most likely outcome if you were to propose a Debian site), I don't think it'd garner much participation since the experts in that subject that use SE are already on the other sites.

### Using Filters to only see what you want

While we can't get you everything in one place, we do have tools within the sites to allow you to narrow what you see to the subjects you want. You can create custom filters that are saved for quick access in the right sidebar, so you can access only the content you are interested in.

[image: Custom filter tool to show user how they can limit what they see by filtering]

### A hub for related content

This would actually be a really cool idea - and something the CMs at least have poked at in discussions before. That said, it'd be a huge change from the current system and I doubt it'd ever actually happen. There are a ton of ways we could do this but the core goal would be to find a way to give users easy cross-site accessibility/visibility of all questions related to something.

While we'd be more likely to do this in context of technology like Debian, it could benefit a lot of sites - such as the overlap between groups of related sites like Movies & TV, Sci-Fi & Fantasy, Anime & Manga, Literature. We know these sites overlap; if we could find a way to do it thoughtfully, it'd be a really great way of bringing the sites together and make it easier for people to find the answers they need.

I know a lot of people aren't convinced by the Collectives project but I think it's actually doing some things that might make solving the issue at question easier. Right now, Collectives are focused on making subsets of content based on related tags/subjects. That's very similar to what I'm talking about here, except that these hubs would pull in content from across the network, not SO only. If we think about Collectives in a network-wide way, it would potentially have much greater benefit and increase participation on network sites.

### A site for Debian

In the end, while you're welcome to suggest a Debian site, I hope that my answer here explains that it's unlikely to make it through Area 51 and even if it does, there will likely be years of content-creation to even reach parity with existing content on established sites. In the end, you'd end up with **four** sites you need to check for content instead of only three.

[image: "How Standard Proliferate" comic by XKCD but with "Standards" replaced with "Stack Exchange Sites".]
(Image from [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/927/), used in compliance with CC BY-NC 2.5)

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of https://stackexchange.com features that were introduced several years ago that were intended to help with this:

1. Global Search
2. Filtered Questions

Since the company adopted Stack Overflow as its corporate identity, the changes done on https://stackexhange.com are minimal. The most recent campaign uses **OverflowAI**.

---

## Global Search

This is close to how site search works, as it allows the use of some search features like tag keywords, i.e.,

- [[debian]](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdebian%5D) returns all the posts across all the Stack Exchanges sites tagged `debian`,
- [[debian] is:question](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdebian%5D%20is%3Aquestion) returns all the questions across all the Stack Exchange sites tagged `debian`.

There are some known issues. Sometimes, it might be better to use Google. "Your mileage might vary".

## Stack Exchange Filtered Questions

Stack Exchange has a feature called Filters. A filter lists questions that match the filter criteria:

Tags

- All questions
- Match selected tags

Sites

- All Sites
- Selected Sites

Filters could be shared.

There are alternatives, like RSS feed aggregators, Google Alerts and others. "Your mileage might vary".

## OverflowAI

There are several experiments under this "umbrella". None of them has yet a direct impact on improving the user site-crossover experience.

### Discussion on Collectives

Collectives is a package of features available in Stack Overflow. A Collective is set by grouping Stack Overflow tags. Currently, there are nine Collectives, but none of them is yet directly related to Debian, but they are running a Discussions experiment. It might be worth keeping an eye on this as, in future stages, the Discussion feature might be less enclosed than the current sites.

Notes:

*[Your mileage might vary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/your_mileage_may_vary)* means that each person's experience might differ depending on their circumstances.